# What are the frequencies displayed in /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: linux, cpu, proc, cpu-frequency

I have a quad core cpu (core i7 7700) with hyperthreading.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz
```

returns 8 different frequencies, some of which are not repeated (for example I can get a single value of 3914.208 MHz). So it does look like the displayed values are the frequencies of each thread, and these frequencies need not to be equal by pairs. Is this possible? In other words, is it possible that 2 threads of a single core have different frequencies (on IRC I'm told that no and they are saying this behavior is very strange, hence my question here). If not, then what are the displayed frequencies?

Here is a real output of the above command:

```
cpu MHz     : 799.804
cpu MHz     : 861.987
cpu MHz     : 1178.613
cpu MHz     : 867.260
cpu MHz     : 3418.066
cpu MHz     : 800.024
cpu MHz     : 1302.539
cpu MHz     : 799.804
```

Edit : With

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

I can see that the MHz corresponds to core 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2 and 3 in that order. So, like Hamza Jabbour says, it's the frequency of each thread (also called logical core).

I'd like to know whether it's possible that each thread have its own frequency and whether /proc/cpuinfo gather the data about frequency in more than 1 cpu cycle (which could make the frequency of virtual cores not matching by pairs, I think.)

Comment: BTW, whenever you `grep` and get information you don't understand, *read the complete text* with `less` or similar. There are so many questions here by people who just `grep` something and throw away all valuable information that would have explained things.

Comment: Fine but this didn't help me to know whether /proc/cpuinfo gathers the information about the threads in 1 cpu cycle. I'm still not sure yet (the current answer doesn't provide any source) that each thread can have a different frequency at a same time (same cpu cycle). I'm still waiting for an answer to that before I can accept the answer.

Comment: The current frequency is a physical property of the (virtual) core, so it's not "sampled" for a number of "cycles", it's simply read from a processor register, and accurate for the time of reading. (Virtual) core frequency is changed by a certain programs in given intervals, see e.g. [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling).

Comment: Weird that no one wants to answer the question. As additional evidence that a general discussion of CPU scaling is not a sufficient answer, I can get 8 frequencies with 4 physical cores as OP did, but if I boot Windows and look at HWiNFO, I only see 4 core frequencies reported.

Answer (score 5):

This is the frequency of your cores, and you have cores which run with the minimum frequency, and other more stressed which run with higher frequency.

You can have more information and explanation with the `lscpu` utility.

Comment: To add to this, Modern CPU's are constantly scalling/throttling depending on load in real time. There are ways to disable all throttling, but it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: But I have only 4 real cores. So what do you mean by "cores"? Threads?

Comment: yes, you have 4 physical cores, and 8 logical cores, in other word, your hyperthreading enable your core to execute 2 threads similtanously.

Comment: in adition, in output of `lscpu` you will find 2 lines : `Core(s) per socket` and `Thread(s) per core` , each thread is a logical core , in your case i think you have : 4 physical core and 2 thread per core <=> 2x4=8 logical core ^^.

Comment: Ok great. I could also see from which real core the frequencies are given. 
Now I need to know whether it's possible that each thread have its own frequency or whether /proc/cpuinfo gather the data about the frequencies in more than 1 cpu cycle.

Comment: @no_choice99 each thread does not have its own frequency, the entire physical core is throttled up/down depending on load, number of threads, affinity,  priority, required latency. The frequencies aren't gathered or "measured", but commanded/controlled by the kernel power management, it does not change from cycle to cycle, but will change as threads die or are created.

Comment: But how can a two logical cores (part of one physical core) have different frequencies at same time ?